# Recommended USB video capture device

Tags: video, capture

I'm going to do some reverse engineering on a device with a composite video output. It would be great if I could just plug this in to my Ubuntu box and be able to record video as well as view the live stream in a window while I'm working with the device in question.

What **USB video capture** device (with composite video input) would you recommend that is **supported out of the box** on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

There are drivers for EasyCAP devices [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easycapdc60/), but since there are so many EasyCAP clones it might be difficult to know you're buying one that is supported by that driver.

I ended up getting a **Pinnacle Dazzle DVC101**. Plugged it in, started tvtime, and it worked right away. Sound doesn't appear to be working right now, but since I don't need it I won't bother trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I bought LW-UTVFM and It never worked. I tried it on windows and It worked fine on Radio though TV was very bad (Picture is not clear plus no sound). 
So add it in your blacklist and don't think of it!